# Agora-Flutter : PlatformException(-17, request to join channel is rejected, null, null) error

Tags: flutter, agora.io

I'm using right now for video calls the famous quickstart flutter agora from github i've never tried to join a channel before but i'm still getting the error above.
Any recommendations ??

Comment: Hello brother do you found any solution to this problem?

Comment: Yeah i just made token to null and make in my agora account a testing choice with less security instead of secure step

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yeah i just made token to null and make in my agora account a testing choice with less security instead of secure step